# Installing MinionPro fonts on Ubuntu 10.04 running TexLive 2012

Tags: installing, ubuntu, minionpro

I followed the instructions to install MinionPro fonts from this website.
http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2007/12/11/installing-minion-pro-fonts/

However, when I tried to run the tex file at the bottom, I have this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `MinionPro.sty' not found.
```

Running the command `kpsewhich MinionPro.sty` gives the following output:

```
/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/MinionPro/MinionPro.sty
```

So the system knows where MinionPro.sty is, so why can't the file compile?

Comment: Did you start `tex` in the same shell where you started `kpsewhich`?

Comment: Hi Stephan, how do I find that out? Not really familar with the kpsewhich command.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. You reported the output of `kpsewhich`, so you probably typed that into a command shell. Is this the same shell where you are also running the `tex` command (or `pdftex` or whatever)?

Comment: Yup it is. I am trying to compile the tex file using pdflatex, if that is of any help.

Comment: That's bad. There's practically no explanation for `kpsewhich` finding the file and `pdflatex` not. Something else must be going wrong.

Comment: Try `ls -l /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/MinionPro/MinionPro.sty`. Maybe the file has wrong permissions?

Comment: Output of that is

-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 24134 2007-05-15 02:40 /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/MinionPro/MinionPro.sty

Comment: Does it find other files in `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/<something>`?  Try also `ls -ld /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/MinionPro`: maybe the permissions on the directory are wrong.

Comment: There is no file such directory called /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/<something>

What should the correct permissions be anyway?

Oh and the permissions on the directory are as follows:
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4096 2012-09-03 17:31

Comment: The funny thing is that when I tried to install the mnsymbol package using the instructions listed on the page, it works fine. The only other thing I can see which may have gone wrong is when I was trying to add the MinionPro.map into my updmap.cfg file.

Where exactly is this updmap.cfg file? Different websites give different answer. How do I find out where is the correct file to enter the map command to?

Comment: You should at first solve the problem that LaTeX doesn't find `MinionPro.sty`. (For me it sounds as if you have two TeXsystems, but a log-file would show more). If there is a problem with the map-file it should be tackled later. Beside this: in TeXLive you don't manipulate `updmap.cfg` directly but use `updmap(-sys) --enable NameOfMap.map`

Comment: Any way to find out if I have only one or more tex systems in my PC?

Comment: Search for latex.exe or pdflatex.exe. Check the pathes and versions in the log-file and compare them with the output of kpsewhich. Check your path variable....

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, so there is no exe files :)

Anyway, as I said earlier, the test file for MnSymbol works perfectly, so I tried checking out it's log file.

There is this entry in the log file.

`/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.sty
Package: MnSymbol 2007/01/21 v1.4 support for the MnSymbol font`

When I did a kpsewhich MnSymbol.sty, I got the following output:


`/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/MnSymbol/MnSymbol.sty`

Is LaTeX doing the correct thing? Sorry for asking such a simple question, but how do I check my path variable?

Comment: Ok. Figured out how to print out my PATH. It's
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the math font, there's a much easier way to use MinionPro with LaTeX:

- Install Acrobat Reader (the `acroread` package on Ubuntu);
- Copy the OTF fonts: `sudo cp /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Resource/Font/*.otf /usr/local/share/fonts/`;
- Use `fontspec` with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX to make use of the fonts.

Comment: Hi Raphink, 

Unfortunately, I need the math fonts as I am typesetting my thesis.