# how to install minion pro under ubuntu

Tags: pdftex, packages, miktex, texlive

I will want to install minion pro under ibuntu but I did not succeed, because it asks me for the .otf file that I do not have, I am looking for a step by step method to install minion pro very clear and easy.
   I tried a lot of times but nothing at all, under windows and ubuntu, it seems to me that it's very difficult to install this package, it's a real headache, I'm looking for any solution to this problem, may be a latex IDE which contains by defaul minion pro, or a vmware image which is preconfigured for the edition of latex documents.
     thank you for giving me an emergency respon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing MinionPro fonts on Ubuntu 10.04 running TexLive 2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69893/installing-minionpro-fonts-on-ubuntu-10-04-running-texlive-2012)

Comment: There are a lot of good fonts out there that work out of the box with latex (see https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/) do you have a specific reason for using MinionPro? Give that you don't even have the font (it's not free).